# Azure Terraform Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines Error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Can someone give me some context as to what this error specifically means. I'm pulling the example from the documentation. I have my code provided below to show what I have created. I used the Terraform documentation to build the resources out.

I'm running into this issue and just trying to understand the error as why its occuring when I'm copy pasting sample code from the documentation. I understand the resolution may be something of the lines of <>EOT

```
   terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Create a resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "mtc-rm" {
  name     = "mtc-rm"
  location = "East Us"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "mtc-network" {
  name                = "mtc-network"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.location
  address_space       = ["10.123.0.0/16"]

  tags = {
    enviroment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "mtc-vn" {
  name                = "mtc-vn"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.location
  address_space       = ["10.123.0.0/16"]

  tags = {
    enviroment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mtc-subnet" {

  name                 = "mtc-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.mtc-vn.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.123.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group "mtc-sg" {
    name  = "mtc-sg" 
    location = azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.name

 tags = {
    environment = "Dev"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "mtc-dev-rule" {
  name                        = "mtc-dev-rule"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Outbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "*"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.mtc-rm.name
}
```

Actual Error Issue:

```
   │ Error: Invalid multi-line string
│
│   on main.tf line 72:
│   72:   }
│   73: }
│
│ Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines. To produce a multi-line string, either use the \n escape to represent a newline character or use the "heredoc" multi-line template syntax.
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_security_rule

Comment: If the question is accurate then you have a typo of a missing quote.

Comment: I still got the error but now it magically works! hooray.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision the resources mentioned in the code via Terraform. Making some changes in the code mentioned I was able to deploy successfully.

To achieve this configuration, I referred the documentation from Terraform1 Terraform2 Registries. These help me in providing a better understanding of errors in code.

- In the code line
  **resource "azurerm_network_security_group "mtc-sg"**
  Quotes are missing after the word "group".
- For the error mentioned in the query we can add the syntax

here is the module we can add

```
 tags = <<EOF
  {
    environment = "dev"
  }
EOF
```

This will define a multi-line string for the `tags` block using the `<<EOF` and `EOF` delimiters. However, we can run existing script with or without this module as we are provided with incomplete script info.

Now make the necessary changes and update the provider to the latest main.tf file goes as follows.

My **main.tf**:

```
 provider  "azurerm" {
   features {}   
    subscription_id  =  "00000000000000000"
    
    client_id  =  "0000000000000000000"
    
    tenant_id  =  "000000000000000000"
    
    client_secret  =  "0000000000000000000"
    
    }
    
      
    
 
    
    resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "mtc-rm" {

name  =  "demorgvk"

location  =  "East Us"

}

  

resource  "azurerm_virtual_network"  "mtc-network" {

name  =  "mtc-network"

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.name

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.location

address_space  =  ["10.123.0.0/16"]

  

tags  =  {

enviroment  =  "dev"

}

}

  

resource  "azurerm_virtual_network"  "mtc-vn" {

name  =  "mtc-vn"

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.name

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.location

address_space  =  ["10.123.0.0/16"]

  

tags  =  {

enviroment  =  "dev"

}

}

  

resource  "azurerm_subnet"  "mtc-subnet" {

  

name  =  "mtc-subnet"

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.name

virtual_network_name  =  azurerm_virtual_network.mtc-vn.name

address_prefixes  =  ["10.123.1.0/24"]

}

  

resource  "azurerm_network_security_group"  "mtc-sg" {

name  =  "mtc-sg-demo"

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.location

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.name

  

tags  =  {

environment  =  "Dev"

}

}

  

resource  "azurerm_network_security_rule"  "mtc-dev-rule" {

name  =  "mtc-dev-rule"

priority  =  100

direction  =  "Outbound"

access  =  "Allow"

protocol  =  "Tcp"

source_port_range  =  "*"

destination_port_range  =  "*"

source_address_prefix  =  "*"

destination_address_prefix  =  "*"

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rm.name

network_security_group_name  =  azurerm_network_security_group.mtc-sg.name


}
```

**Output:**

while doing `terraform_plan`

[image]

while doing `terraform_apply`

[image]

[image]

[image]

By making the necessary changes mentioned in syntax, duplicate resource modules and updating the provider to latest version we will be able to provision the resource successfully.